# Can we use apply function along with some user defined function or if/while loops in R to conditionally work it on selective rows?

Tags: r

I know that `while` and `if` functions in R are not vectorised. `while` and `if` functions help us selectively work on some rows based on some condition. I also know that the `apply` function in R is used to apply over the columns and hence it operates on all rows of columns that we wish to put apply on. Can I use `apply()` along with user defined functions and/or with `while/if` loop to conditionally use it over some rows rather than all rows as apply function usually does.

**Note :-** This core issue here is to bypass the drawback on non-vectorization of while/if loops in R.

Comment: FWIW, `apply` is not vectorized and it's just a wrapper of a `for` loop.

Comment: @nicola So can user defined functions be vectorised and used with apply to bypass the above constraint of if/while

Answer (score 0):

You can supply user defined functions to `apply` using an argument `FUN = function(x) user_defined_function(x)  {}`. And `apply` is "vectorized" in sense that as argument it accept vectors, not scalars (but its implementation is heavily using `for` and `if` loops, type `apply` without arguments in your console). So `for` and `apply` are of the same perfomance.

However you can break the execution of user defined function throwing exception with `stop` and wrapping in `tryCatch` it is a non-recommended technique (it influences environements, call stacks, scopes etc., make debugging difficult and lead to errors which are difficult to identify).

Better to use `for` and `if` and very often it is the most easiest and effective way (to write a recursive function, taking in consideration that (tail) recursion is not really optimized for R, or fully refactor your algorithm  quite difficult and time consuming).